Docker Multi Arch Build Failing in Github Actions
I have been manually publishing my docker image to my azure container registry by using the following command:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 -t project.azurecr.io/project:{VERSION_NUMBER} . --push
I am attempting to automate this process using the following Github Workflow per the Docker Documentation on a workflow for multi-arch publishing:
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Log in to Azure Container Registry
        uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: project.azurecr.io 
          username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Read version number
        id: get_version
        run: echo "VERSION_NUMBER=$(cat VERSION)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          push: true
          tags: project.azurecr.io/project:${{ env.VERSION_NUMBER }}

But my Build and Push fails with the following error:
ERROR: Multi-platform build is not supported for the docker driver.
Switch to a different driver, or turn on the containerd image store, and try again.
Please let me know if I am missing anything...
I tried to specify the docker-container driver, I tried to run the docker commands as is, I tried to use different buildkits. I use the moby buildkit on my local.

Is this a public project? If so, please include the project link.

I see that the docker/setup-buildx-action@v3 is mentioned in the code. but it doesn't specify the docker-container driver. Can you add the driver: docker-container parameter to the docker/setup-buildx-action@v3 step. Something like this-
- name: Set up Docker Buildx   uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3   with:     driver: docker-container
